# Do I always get an abundance of just a couple different metal ores?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

When I embark I specifically look for shallow and deep metal with at least a little soil in hopes of getting iron. Which half the time i do get iron and maybe one other different type of metal. The other half of the time i end up with all gold and usually silver. Am i just not looking hard enough?  I feel like there should be a wide variety metals in a certain area.

**Do i always get an abundance of just a couple different ores and miss out of getting to use the rest?**

Comment: I believe you will find this is a result of the world generation process. There is some (very basic) geology built into the models that build up the layers of bedrock. And they try to mimic real life processes that tend to generate a limited variety of minerals in a particular location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, yes, you will get a large number of a couple metals. This is one reason that trade is so important. The density of ores, can, however, be changed before world creation with one of the [world customization options](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:World_generation#Mineral_Occurrence).

Comment: any suggestions on how i can make it so i get more iron then gold?

Comment: Mine goblinite.

Comment: @Paralytic: Use "[prospect](https://github.com/peterix/dfhack/blob/master/Readme.rst#prospect)" from [dfhack](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=91166.0) to check your embarking location.